# C++ auto-vectorization requirements for gcc, clang and msvc

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vectorization, auto-vectorization

Are the following statements correct?

1. With GCC and clang, my code will be auto-vectorized if I compile with :

   - `-O2 -ftree-vectorize -march=XYZ` (XYZ being the target instruction set: native, SSE, AVX2, etc.)
   - `-O3 -march=XYZ`
2. With MSVC, my code will be auto-vectorized if I compile with:

   - `/O2`

[This video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Jim-Radigan-Inside-Auto-Vectorization/Jim-Radigan-Inside-Auto-Vectorization-1-of-n) seems to suggest that I do not need to specify the architecture with MSVC. Is that correct? The compiler will use the native architecture by default, and fall back on scalar operations at runtime if vector instructions can't be found.

Comment: Have you consulted the documentation? First Google result for "visual studio vectorisation" takes me to the page that explains this.

Comment: I vote for: 3. it is wrong to rely on compiler to auto-vectorize my code

Comment: _The Auto-Vectorizer may generate different instructions than specified by the /arch switch. These instructions are guarded by a runtime check to make sure that code still runs correctly. For example, when you compile /arch:SSE2, SSE4.2 instructions may be emitted. A runtime check verifies that SSE4.2 is available on the target processor and jumps to a non-SSE4.2 version of the loop if the processor does not support those instructions._ Basically, (my understanding) it generates multiple versions and at run time decides which to use.

Comment: This is the part of the documentation that was confusing me. It implies that my binaries are extremely bloated, as they contain two or three different versions of my program. That sounds surprising to me, which is why I posted this question in the first place.

Comment: You can view the disassembly to see exactly what it's doing. Also remember that most code can't actually be vectorized, so it's not adding too too much code.

Comment: Note that I am working on a large scientific code, which contains a large number of vectorizable loops. It is rather difficult to look at the generated assembly code because the codebase is so massive...I am trying to use Intel Advisor to figure out what's going on right now.

Answer (score 4):

> I do not need to specify the architecture with MSVC. Is that correct?

Yes that is indeed correct. With MSVC, By default, the Auto-Vectorizer is enabled and picks up appropriate instructurion set for fastest vectorization. Moreover, even if you do specify `arch`, The Auto-Vectorizer may generate different instructions than specified by the `/arch` switch - as stated by [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/auto-parallelization-and-auto-vectorization?view=vs-2019). For example, when you compile `/arch:SSE2`, `SSE4.2` instructions may be emitted.

On another note, The VS vectorizer lacks quite a bit of features when compared to gcc or clang.

> With GCC and clang, my code will be auto-vectorized if I compile with `-O2 -ftree-vectorize -march=XYZ` ? `-O3 -march=XYZ ?`

Not necessarily, To enable vectorization of floating point reductions you need to  use `-ffast-math` or `-fassociative-math` as well. However, in general, Yes it'll be enabled. You may find same written in [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html), *Vectorization is enabled by the flag -ftree-vectorize and by default at -O3*

PS: You may use https://godbolt.org to see all this in action!